# What happens to the memory allocated by `new` if the constructor throws?

Tags: c++

Will this code cause a memory leak?

```
#include <stdexept>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Test");
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        MyClass * myClass = new MyClass;
    }
    catch (const std::exception & exc)
    {
        // Memory leak?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The memory allocated by `new` is never deleted. Is this taken care of internally, or it an actual memory leak?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The memory will be automatically freed before the exception propagates.

This is essential, because a) the program never receives a pointer to free, and b) even if it did, it would have no portable way to actually free it since the memory never became an object that you can delete.

Answer (score 13):

The memory will be properly deallocated.

Related questions at SO.

[Is it ever not safe to throw an exception in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197566/is-it-ever-not-safe-to-throw-an-exception-in-a-constructor)

[C++ : handle resources if constructors may throw exceptions (Reference to FAQ 17.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230423/c-handle-resources-if-constructors-may-throw-exceptions-reference-to-faq-17)

```
prasoon@prasoon-desktop ~ $ cat noleak.cpp && g++ noleak.cpp && valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
#include <stdexcept>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Test");
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        MyClass * myClass = new MyClass;
    }
    catch (const std::exception & exc)
    {
        // Memory leak?
    }
    return 0;
}
==3652== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3652== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3652== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3652== Command: ./a.out
==3652== 
==3652== 
==3652== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3652==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3652==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 106 bytes allocated
==3652== 
==3652== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3652== 
==3652== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3652== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 6)
prasoon@prasoon-desktop ~ $
```

Answer (score 7):

> $15.2/2 - "An object that is partially
>   constructed or partially destroyed
>   will have destructors executed for all
>   of its fully constructed base classes
>   and non-variant members, that is, for
>   subobjects for which the principal
>   constructor (12.6.2) has completed
>   execution and the destructor has not
>   yet begun execution. Similarly, if the
>   non-delegating constructor for an
>   object has completed execution and a
>   delegating constructor for that object
>   exits with an exception, the object’s
>   destructor will be invoked. **If the
>   object was allocated in a
>   new-expression, the matching
>   deallocation function (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4,
>   12.5), if any, is called to free the storage occupied by the object.**"