# std::unique_ptr::reset and constructor exceptions

Tags: c++, memory-management, exception, constructor

If initialise a `unique_ptr` like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> i;
i.reset( new Foo() );
```

but an exception is thrown from `Foo::Foo()`, the question is: what happens with the memory allocated? how does unique_ptr avoid it being leaked? is this something handled inside `new` operator?

The destructor will certainly be called when the scope exits. Since the `reset` call is not invoked until `new Foo()` returns, it seems that this must be handled by `new`, by freeing the allocated memory when the exception leaves the constructor.

Is that what happens?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094996/what-happens-to-the-memory-allocated-by-new-if-the-constructor-throws

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If an exception is thrown in the constructor of `Foo`, then the `reset` function of the unique pointer never gets executed in the first place. Thus the unique pointer retains its original value.

A `new` expression doesn't leak memory if the object construction throws an exception.

Comment: And if you have `make_unique`, one can use `i = make_unique<Foo>()`.

Comment: no, should be Ok (no managed pointer), but I can not find anything in documentation

Comment: @Nick: Please do at least try to compile that.

Comment: not sure if c-tor is explicit, this should be compiled correctly - `std::unique_ptr p{ new Bla() };`