# chaining constructors in Java without throwing exceptions from the default constructor

Tags: java, exception, constructor, constructor-chaining

I've read this: [Can I use throws in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789989/can-i-use-throws-in-constructor) -- which gave me the right idea, and led me to one answer, but was not very explicit. I've also read several others, but could not find my answer. To recap what I've learned for context, essentially, this will not compile...

```
public ExampleClass(String FileName)
{
   this(new FileInputStream(FileName));
}

public ExampleClass(FileInputStream FileStream)
{
   DoSomethingToSetupBasedUponFileStream(FileStream);
}
```

...because the `FileInputStream` constructor (called from the String Constructor) may throw a FileNotFoundException. You can still create the constructor by making **it** throw the same exception as follows:

```
public ExampleClass(String FileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
   this(new FileInputStream(FileName));
}
```

My question is related to a default constructor (no arguments) that would simply use a default filename String constant:

```
public ExampleClass() throws FileNotFoundException
{
   this(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME);
}
```

This would chain the constructors as:

`ExampleClass()` --> `ExampleClass(<String>)` --> `ExampleClass(<InputFileStream>)`

**In a case like this, is it possible to use a default value (static final class member) in the default constructor, to instantiate (further down the chain) a FileInputStream, but not have to use the `throws FileNotFoundException` code (which would require someone using the class to either re-throw or handle the exception?**

If I could do something like the following, I would handle the exception myself:

```
public ExampleClass()
{
   try
   {
      this(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      DoSomethingToHandleException(e);
   }
}
```

...However, as far as I know this is not possible, because the "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor"

Being more used to .Net at this point, I've never been **forced** to deal with exceptions if I didn't really want to... :D

Comment: though none of the answers really make me say "Oh Yeah!, that's what I should do!" they are all generally helpful, so thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your file construction code out of your constructor, so you could do something like this --

```
public ExampleClass() {
  try {
      fileInputStreamMethod(DEFAULT_FILE);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    ...
  }

public ExampleClass(String fileName) throws Exception {
    fileInputStreamMethod(fileName);
}

private void fileInputStreamMethod(String fileName) throws Exception {
    // your file handling methods
}
```

Comment: Though I'd love to not have to workaround, this does seem to me to be the best option in it's simplicity and transparency to the user. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you cannot catch an exception from the call to this(...).

You could use a static method to produce what you want:

```
static ExampleClass createDefault()
{
  try
  {
    return new ExampleClass(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    DoSomethingToHandleException(e)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Though it seems like it would work, it does seem to digress a little too much from the whole constructor approach (in it's lack of transparency to the user) - I'll keep it in mind for when it seems more elegant or appropriate to the situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public ExampleClass(String FileName)
{
   this(getStream(FileName));
}

private static FileInputStream getStream(String name) {
    try {
        return new FileInputStream(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log error
        return null;
    }
}
```

The real question is, why would you *not* want to throw an exception? How should your program behave if the file cannot be opened? I think it would be unusual that you would want it to proceed as if there were no problem. Quite likely, the `null` input stream will cause grief later on.

In general, you're better off throwing an exception as close to the source of an error as possible.

Comment: I think that Code Jockey implicitly assumes that DEFAULT_FILE_NAME will work.  Perhaps Code Jockey could throw a RuntimeException to indicate that one of his operating assumptions had been violated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have to do is do the work that your constructor has to do in a different method(something that's not a constructor) and then use it in the default constructor. But am not sure how useful this technique is in your scenario.

cheers!