# Use of try/catch inside constructor calling another constructor

Tags: java, oop, exception, constructor

I m having a problem of calling a constructor with arguments from default constructor.

```
   Class A {            
             private static Properties properties;

             A(Properties property){

                 // do some checks
                    try{
                      load(property, fileName)
                     } catch(IOException e) {
                       throw new RuntimeException();
                     }
                 }

             A(){
                   this(load(properties));
                }

            private static Properties load(Properties properties, String fileName ) throws IOException {
               try {
                    properties.load(A.class.getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream(fileName));
                   } catch (IOException ioException) {
                    throw new IOException("Unable to process the properties File. " + fileName, ioException);
                  }

                return properties;
             }
    }
```

My problem is: In Default constructor I wanted to use try/catch block and do the same operation of throwing a run time exception. Can you help me out as what can be done in this?

WRT this post: [chaining constructors in Java without throwing exceptions from the default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125824/chaining-constructors-in-java-without-throwing-exceptions-from-the-default-const?rq=1)

I have an option of putting try/catch inside another method. But is there any other way?
P.S: I do not want to use 'throws'

Comment: What are you *exactly* trying to do? Can you clear out your post a bit?

Comment: I m trying to have two constructors. One with arguments and one, default. If consumer of my class doesn't call argument constructor I need to load automatically and pass it onto the constructor with arguments

Comment: Post your load function

Comment: Then you'll either need a pre-loaded, "default" properties object to be passed to the 1-arg constructor, or pass null and handle it.

Comment: If super class's constructor throws an exception, object is very likely to be in invalid state - which is why you are not allowed to catch the exception

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Option 1**: Pass the other constructor a new empty instance of Properties:

```
class A
{ 
  public A()
  {
    this(new Properties());
  }

  // rest of code...
}
```

**Option 2**: Pass the other constructor a null instance of Properties. You'll then have to guard against null in `load(...)`, but you probably should be anyway:

```
class A
{ 
  public A()
  {
    this(null);
  }

  // rest of code...
}
```

**Option 3**: Pass the other constructor a default instance of Properties:

```
class A
{
  private static final Properties defaultProperties;
  static
  {
     defaultProperties = new Properties();
     // populate here however you wish
  }

  public A()
  {
    this(defaultProperties);
  }

  // rest of code...
}
```

Comment: Might want to add final keyword to static field

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow chained constructor calls to be enclosed within a `try` block, since such constructs could if not restricted allow an object whose base object threw an exception to end up being returned to calling code.  This makes it difficult to express certain concepts involving resources like files [e.g. it would be helpful to have a constructor open a file before chaining to the parent and close it afterward, but there's no way to safely have a constructor take responsibility for a file which is opened before chaining to the parent].  The best one can do in Java is avoid public constructors which might throw exceptions and instead use factory methods which can be better equipped to handle them.